# Orca will not start on Ubuntu 16.04 or 16.10 installers

Tags: system-installation, orca

Orca will not start with the standard installer keyboard shortcut. Also, if I try to manually launch it, such as from within the terminal, Orca starts, reads the window title, then immediately exits.

Comment: Anything of interest in the log files?

Comment: I am having the same issue where Orca will not start up in the installer with Ubuntu 16.10 or Ubuntu 17.04. I relie on Orca because I am blind. You might be able to update to Ubuntu 16.10 or 17.4 if you first install an earlier version of Ubuntu, then go to software update and then update to the latest version. I don't know if this will prevent Orca from reading anything on the screen, I am going to back up the virtual machine and try to upgrade and see if Orca still works.